# jQuery $.fn.myfunction is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Code.

[[A]] // jquery.fn.code

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.flash = function(duration) {
        this.animate({opacity:0},duration);
        this.animate({opacity:0},duration);
    }; 
})( jQuery );
```

1.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    [[A]]
    ...
    ...
    if($("#testID").length != 0 ) {
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#testID").flash(700);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

2.

```
[[A]]

$(document).ready(function() {

    ...
    ...
    if($("#testID").length != 0 ) {
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#testID").flash(700);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

3.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ...
    ...
    if($("#testID").length != 0 ) {
        setInterval(function() {
            [[A]]
            $("#testID").flash(700);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

1 and 2 are not working. (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flash')
but 3 is working.

Same result for [[A]] code changing into just "$.fn.flash = ..." , "jQuery.fn.flash = ..." or "jQuery.fn.extend({flash:..."

I dont know why not working..

Of course, at the top of this code is loaded jQuery lib.

Please help me. T^T

Comment: For next time please use a jsfiddle.net :)

Answer (score 0):

Try make a extension of jquery:

```
$.fn.extend({
        name_function: function (param) {
            //do something
        }
    });

<a onclick="javascript:$(this).name_function(1);"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

do in this order:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.flash = function(duration) {
            this.animate({opacity:0},duration);
            this.animate({opacity:0},duration);
        }; 

        if($("#testID").length != 0 ) {
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#testID").flash(700);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, with some minor changes, see http://jsfiddle.net/QXt25/

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.flash = function(duration) {
        this.animate({opacity:0},duration).animate({opacity:100},duration);
    }; 
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#testID").length != 0 ) {
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#testID").flash(500);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```